# Draw rectangle graph when multiple rows exist in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 2 rows data as follows :

```
STA0 = 

     '0 -> 2 1.000000 1.000200 A-MPDU 1.000000 1.000100 SUCCESS 1.000100 1.000200 FAIL NO'
     '0 NO NaN 1.000270 1.000570 BACKOFF NaN NaN NO NaN NaN NO NO'
```

I want to make graph in Matlab like this :

[image]

So far I only can make graph when only one row exists thus Backoff rectangle doesn't exist.

[image]

How to make these 2 rows can be drawn as graph above ?

Comment: Please show us what code you have so far.  Also, can't you just reuse the same logic, but have a `hold on` before the next `plot` call?

Comment: I use the code from my previous question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904965/draw-rectangle-based-on-data-in-matlab?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

To draw colored rectangles, check out this [Saturn Fiddle](https://saturnapi.com/vpartition/colored-rectangles).

```
figure;
hold all;
xlim([0,1]);
ylim([0,1]);
set(gca,'visible','off');
rectangle('Position',[0,0,.5,.5],'FaceColor',[1,0,0]);
rectangle('Position',[.5,.5,.2,.2],'FaceColor',[0,0,1],'EdgeColor',[0,0,0],'Linewidth',4,'Linestyle','--');
print("MyPNG.png", "-dpng")
```

You can customize the code above for your case.